# Livewire Turbolink Site jumped twice when navigate

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, turbolinks

I have used Laravel 10 with Livewire 3 and Turbolink.

When I navigate site from one page to another page, page jumps twice.

I am getting below two error message in console.

Detected multiple instances of Livewire running
Detected multiple instances of Alpine running

Any solution for this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why you want to use turbolink in Livewire 3?

Comment: I wan to give effect same as SPA by using turbolink.

Comment: You can use `navigate()` for that, check this https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/navigate#basic-usage

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I removed turbolink and used navigate() and my issue solved. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I removed turbolink and used navigate() and my issue solved.